# Regular expression to get the string including the starting character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this

```
var str="|Text|Facebook|Twitter|";
```

I am trying to get any one of the word with its preceding pipe sign so something like

`|Text` or `|Facebook` or `|Twitter`

I thought of below two patterns but they didn't work

```
/|Facebook/g  //returned nothing
/^|Facebook/g // returned "Facebook" but I want "|Facebook"
```

What should I use to get `|Facebook`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape `|` char:

```
/\|Facebook/g
```

Comment: Thanks Man! So simple and easy :)

Answer (score 3):

The pipe is special character in a regular expression. `A|B` matches `A` **or** `B`.

You have to escape the pipe to match `|` literally.

```
var str = '|Text|Facebook|Twitter|'
str.match(/\|\w+/g) // => ["|Text", "|Facebook", "|Twitter"]
```

`\w` matches any alphabet, digit, `_`.

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the detailed description!

Comment: `|` is a *pipe*, not a backslash.